# Setting position of Navbar to fixed makes dropdown stop working

Tags: html, css, navbar

I programmed a navbar for my website, and one of the items was a dropdown menu. The dropdown was working, but when I set the position of the navbar to fixed so that it will stay with the page even when you scroll down, the dropdown stops working.
here is the before code

```
/*CSS*/
body{
        font-family: Optima, Courier, Ariel;
        background-color:#000000;
        background-image: url('background.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    .navbar {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #000000;
        max-height: 68px;
    }

    .navbar a {
        float: left;
        font-size: 25px;
        color: #00cc00;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px 40px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .dropdown {
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .dropdown .dropbtn {
        font-size: 25px;  
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        color: #00cc00;
        padding: 20px 40px;
        background-color: inherit;
        font-family: inherit;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: #00cc00;
        color: #000000;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #00cc00;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(120,150,120,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
        float: none;
        color: #000000;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {
        background-color: #000000;
        color: #00cc00
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }
    div.centered{
        background-color:#111111;
        margin-left:10%;
        margin-right:10%;
        color:#00cc00;
    }
```

```
<!--HTML-->
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#home"><img src="logo.png" width = "48" height = "32"></a>
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown &#9660</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href = "#item1">item1</a>
            <a href = "#item2">item2</a>
            <a href = "#item3">item3</a>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then I only changed the css of the navbar to this

```
.navbar {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #000000;
        max-height: 68px;
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
    }
```

When I made this change the navbar wasn't affected by scrolling, and it looked the same, but the dropdown stopped working.
Is there a solution that allows me to keep both features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to fix it.

Here is the CSS code.
I changed

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

to

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    position:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting the elements, I found that everything is working as expected, but there is one mistake you made, you added `overflow: hidden` to `.navbar` at line 11 which is why your dropdown was not visible.

Here's the codepen [link](https://codepen.io/prathameshkoshti/pen/dyowQmO?editors=0100) where I've commented that line.

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

yah there is a solution and its very simple, just retain this

```css
.navbar {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #000000;
        max-height: 68px;
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
    }
```

but also add `position:fixed` to the `.dropdown-content` class, your dropdown-content class should now look like this

```css
 .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        background-color: #00cc00;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(120,150,120,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

this way you will maintain your dropdown and still fix the position of your navbar